# Testing effect of provider updates

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm attempting to flesh put my understanding of Jest testing as some of my components are lacking subsequent testing. Consider this:

```
import React, { ReactElement, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IPlaylist } from "src/interfaces/playlist";
import usePlaylists from "src/providers/playlists/hooks/use-playlists";

const JestTesting = (): ReactElement => {

  const { playlists, addPlaylist } = usePlaylists();

  const examplePlaylist = {
    id: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}`,
    name: "testing",
    created: new Date().toISOString(),
    createdBy: "Biggus Dickus",
    updated: new Date().toISOString(),
    version: 0,
    tracks: []
  };

  const createPlaylist = () =>
    addPlaylist(examplePlaylist);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (playlists.length > 0) {
      console.log("playlists updated")
    }
  }, [playlists]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Jest Testing</h2>
      {playlists.map((p) => <h3 key={p.id}>{p.name}</h3>)}
      <button onClick={ () => createPlaylist() }>
        Create New Playlist
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default JestTesting;
```

This is just a very simple component that leverages the custom provider I made; the provider (in this component) has an initial playlist value of an empty array and a function for updating that array.

Here's the test:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, RenderResult, fireEvent, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import JestTesting from "..";

const mockPlaylists = jest.fn().mockReturnValue([]);
const mockAddPlaylist = jest.fn();

// First mock provider attempt
jest.mock("src/providers/playlists/hooks/use-playlists", () => () => {
  return {
    playlists: mockPlaylists(),
    addPlaylist: mockAddPlaylist
  };
});

const clickCreatNewPlaylistBtn = () =>
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText("Create New Playlist"));

describe("JestTesting", () => {
  let rendered: RenderResult;
  const renderComponent = () => render(<JestTesting />);

  beforeEach(() => {
    rendered = renderComponent();
  });

  it("renders the component", () => {
    expect(rendered.container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  describe("when new playlist is created", () => {
    it("updates view/snapshot", () => {
      clickCreatNewPlaylistBtn();
      expect(mockAddPlaylist).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(rendered.container).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });

});
```

which spits out this snapshot:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1, 

exports[`JestTesting renders the component 1`] = `
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>
      Jest Testing
    </h2>
    <button>
      Create New Playlist
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
`;

exports[`JestTesting when new playlist is created updates view/snapshot 1`] = `
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>
      Jest Testing
    </h2>
    <button>
      Create New Playlist
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

The tests pass and I can see that the `mockAddPlaylist` function is called, but the problem is that the playlists array in the snapshot is never updated and the snapshots don't change between the first and the second test.

What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to wait for the effects of the `addPlaylist` function to finish? If so, what's the best way to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you expect it to be updated? mockAddPlaylist is a noop and mockPlaylists is always an empty array.

Comment: Because, in the app, when a component calls the addPlaylist() function it updates the state of playlists by adding an object to it. But based on what you just said, noop, are you implying that I'd need to provide an actual implementation for it to work?

Comment: Depending on your testing strategy, you need to either not mock usePlaylists, which will make it integration test, or mock it in more meaningful way, like mocking mockPlaylists with non-empty array when you expect it to be non-empty, which will make it unit test. This will also require to re-render a component so it makes sense to use React Testing Library, otherwise you'll have to write rerender thing by yourself. Any way, usePlaylists should be tested separately, so it makes sense to stick to unit tests for this component.

Comment: Hmm - I'll see if I can work through it based on what you've said - any examples you can point me to?

Comment: Not specific ones, no. See https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/reference/api for to test real hook implementation, https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#rerender to update the component after mockPlaylists return value is changed.